# Why have multiple ItemGroup and ItemDefinitionGroups?

Tags: c++, msbuild

I've been working to create my msbuild *.vcxproj file from scratch to get a better understanding what msbuild does.  In examples like [this](https://github.com/neilmendoza/ofxPtf/blob/master/example/example.vcxproj) and for examples on MSDN, why is there a ItemGroup for a `ClCompile` tasks and a separate ItemGroup for a `ClInclude` tasks.  Could you just lump them all into one ItemGroup?  I also see multiple ItemDefinitionGroups in the example linked.  Why have multiple of these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a personal taste. You can group things that logically belong together into item / property groups.

A practical reason for separation would be if you'd need to apply a `Condition` attribute - you can put a condition on a group instead of applying the same condition to multiple items / properties / *.

For projects that are generated by tooling, some tools may emit each item group separately and not implement additional logic to merge condition-less groups. This is just an implementation detail of such tooling.